# The application icon is not hidden even though I did LEANBACK_LAUNCHER

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-manifest

Although I did this in the AndroidManifest.xml, the icon is not hidden on the Huawei p30 device. Icon hiding on samsung and xiaomi devices.

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

I need to hide the icon on huawei devices. How can I do?